# Jacobian elliptic function argument

Tags: elliptic-functions

I have a `C++` code that computes jacobian elliptic `sn`, `cn` and `dn`.

```
void elipticjacobi(double u, double m, double * sn, double * cn, double * dn) {
    if(fabs(m) > 1.0) {
        *sn = 0.0;
        *cn = 0.0;
        *dn = 0.0;
        //error code
    }
    ....
}
```

If I calculate `sn(2,0.2)` with my code, and if I calculate `sn(2,0.2)` with WolframAlpha I am getting the same result and the result is `0.953667`.

The elliptic function second argument must be `|m|<1` but if I calculate `sn(2,4)` with WolframAlpha I am getting `-0,29`.

What could be the problem?

Comment: You mean $|m|<1$, not $|x|>1$, right?

Comment: @HansLundmark you are right, I have just edited my question.

Comment: Are you asking why your error code fails to return the values you set?  You don't show a return statement in the snippet above.  It really isn't a mathematical or algorithmic problem that you posed.

Answer (score 2):

Mathematica (which WA is built upon) implements the Jacobi elliptic functions $\operatorname{sn}(z,m)$ etc. not just for $0<m<1$ but also for complex values of $m$; the [documentation for JacobiSN](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/JacobiSN.html) says that it's a meromorphic function in both arguments. But I haven't managed to find the exact definition in the documentation. It's $\operatorname{sn}(z,m) = \sin \operatorname{am}(z,m)$, and the [documentation for JacobiAmplitude](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/JacobiAmplitude.html) says a little about branch cuts and $m>1$ at least. Perhaps someone at the [Mathematica SE](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/) would know more about the details?